# How do I get the latest linux kernel, and why would I want to do that in the first place?

Tags: linux, installation, upgrade, kernel, compile

I'm running 3.10-3-686-pae, and I think I would like to upgrade to 3.12 just so I can learn more about how it all works. My computer runs pretty well considering how old it is. I have been learning to use Linux for a little over two months.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-reasons-update-kernel-linux/) article a bit educational to answer the 'why' portion of your question. As for 'how?' That sort of depends on your particular *flavour* of linux. And compiling a custom kernel can get pretty involved. For me, the most educational experience came from following Gentoo's [guide](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/kernel-upgrade.xml) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

How to get the latest kernel?  Goto kernel.org and download the "mainline" tar.xz file.
Make sure you have plenty of hard drive space.
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.18.3.tar.xz

I normally use opensuse, but you may need to make adjustments to the process for your distribution.

decompress the kernel.

```
says you put it in /usr/src/kernel
goto to that folder.
cd /usr/src/kernel
make localmodconfig
make -j 8 bzImage
make -j 8 modules
make -j 8 modules_install
make -j 8 install

yast bootloader
select the new kernel version and set it active.
reboot and it is active.
```

Answer (score -1):

Linux is highly modular and therefore the kernel is more commonly discussed as a lot can be done with it. For example, you could take the kernel, patch it up with lots of fixes, tweak other settings, strip out everything you won’t need, and then replace your original kernel with your final product, and it will run just fine.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the author's question.  If it does then its not actually clear how it relates.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do it in the first place, actually. Set up the latest( not provided by your distro) versions of development toolchain, and only then start to compile! It will save you alot of time and many errors and warnings just won't appear at all. Use Git sources from kernel.org - and go ahead!

Comment: This really seems more like a comment then an actual answer.

Comment: If you need a command-line sequence - say it, I can provide it. It's alot of strings, so I wasn't posting it from start.

Comment: **I shouldn't have to say it.**  You should have provided it in the first place.

Comment: for Debian-style distro's : `code`sudo -s
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install gcc gcc-multilib g++ bc m4 flex bison libtool automake make preload libncurses5-dev `code` If you have a different distro style - just make sure to download theese packets. After that just : `git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git`. After that in 'linux' directory do the following : `git checkout-idex -a -f --prefix=/path/to/your/buil/dir/` And take extra care for a trailing slash! Use _italic_ make menuconfig _italic_ and carry on!

Comment: Feel free to include all of that in your answer.  Be sure to format it so its readable.